# Regex to check for a specific word, else string should have 1 character in length

Tags: regex

1. Iam trying to come up with a regex to check if the string is not = to the word "Space" then the word should be of length 1 char. The below is something which I tried but still not successful. Expecting some help here.

`((?=^/bSpace/b).*{1})$`

2. In another requirement, Iam trying to perform an regex_replace functionality which should replace special characters in a string starting from 4 position. Expecting some Help here as well.

`([a-zA-Z]{2}-.*(^[0-9a-zA-Z]){1,17})$`

Comment: what language? .....

Comment: I'm Trying to use it in Oracle REGEXP_LIKE function which gets evaluated in a PL/SQL program.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:Space|.)$
```

This should suffice for your first requriement.

For second you can try

```
^(.{4})|([^!@#]*)|[!@#]
```

Replace by `$1$2`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/19

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the first pattern, but still, It does not return true if the word is Space. But if the word is 1 char length, it returns true. I'm trying to make it to return true in both scenarios, if word=Space or word=1 char in length. Any suggestions.